# PHP OO - Associative array of object instances, resetting on each click

Tags: php, arrays, object, associative-array, getter-setter

My first ever question on here as I'm completely stuck, so apologies if I leave out any key information - please let me know!

I am creating a PHP Battleships game and trying to use full OO. I'm really close, however, an array for one of my classes does not hold any updates I make to it.

First off, I dynamically
[created a HTML table with an onclick event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3jSO.png)  - which passes the coordinates to a JS function.

I then make an AJAX call in jQuery:

```
        function shotFired(row, column) {
        var coords = {
            x: row,
            y: column
        };

        $.post("data/game_controller.php", {
            jsonCoords: JSON.stringify(coords)
        }, function(results) {
            console.log(results)
            console.log(results[4])

            var playerShotResult = results[0];
            var computerShotX = results[1] + 1;
            var computerShotY = results[2] + 1;
            var computerShotResult = results[3];

            var positionsClicked = document.getElementById("computer_" + row + "," + column)
            switch (playerShotResult) {
                case "MISS":
                    positionsClicked.classList.add("miss");
                    break;
                case "HIT":
                    positionsClicked.classList.add("hit");
                    break;
                case "Already Hit":
                    document.getElementById("outputMessage").innerHTML = result
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("Player shot defaulted");
            }
        }, "json")
```

I then use **game_controller.php** to handle the request and call **shotFired**:

```
<?php
session_start();
require("../classes/Game.class.php");

if (isset($_POST['jsonCoords'])) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['newGame'])) {
        $game = unserialize($_SESSION['newGame']);

        $coords = json_decode($_POST['jsonCoords']);
        $results = $game->shotFired($coords->x, $coords->y);

        echo json_encode($results);
    }
}
```

**shotFired** from the **Game.php** Class file, gets an instance of the **Fleet** class called computer, and runs the **checkPosition** function:

```
public function shotFired($x, $y)
{
    $computer = $this->getComputer();

    $playerHit = $computer->checkPosition(($x - 1), ($y - 1));
    $computerGrid = $computer->getBattleshipsGrid();
    $computerHit = $this->simulateComputerShot();

    return [$playerHit, $computerHit[0], $computerHit[1], $computerHit[2], $computerGrid];
}
```

**checksPosition** checks the *State* of the **Position** instance in the BattleshipGrid array, and then *attempts* to update the array with a H or M - using a standard setter method:

```
public function checkPosition($x, $y): string
{
    $positionObj = $this->battleshipsGrid["(" . $x . "," . $y . ")"];
    $positionState = $positionObj->getState();

    if ($positionState == "#") {
        $positionObj->setState("M");
        return "MISS";
    } elseif ($positionState == "M" || $positionState == "H") {
        return "Already Fired";
    } else {
        $positionObj->setState("H");
        return "HIT";
    }
}
```

For reference, I set the Battleships board in the constructor for **Fleet.php**:

```
    // Populate associative array with instances of position
    for ($y = 0; $y < $gridSize; $y++) {
        for ($x = 0; $x < $gridSize; $x++) {
            $coordinates = "(" . $x . "," . $y . ")";
            $this->battleshipsGrid[$coordinates] = new Position($x, $y);
        }
    }
```

It works directly after it has been set - however, on the next onclick event, the H or M value is reset to it's previous value?
[Seen here in console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFYvk.png)

After a couple of hours, the closest I've come to is passing byRef in the setState function (didn't make a difference).
I've seen some notes on array_map, but I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for?

For ref, this is how I output the battleshipGrid to the console:

```
    public function getBattleshipsGrid()
{
    $readableGrid = "";
    $grid = $this->battleshipsGrid;
    foreach ($grid as $coordsID => $positionObj) {
        $readableGrid .= "\n" . $coordsID . ": " . $positionObj->getState();
    }

    return $readableGrid;
}
```

Apologies for the long post, but I didn't want to leave anything out. Any and all help would be extremely appreciated!

Many thanks

Comment: After click  can you  write here var_dump of the session new_game out put.    for each click.

Comment: Why do you use `unserialize()` on `$_SESSION` here? It would be fine without any serialization call as the entire session is stored in a serialized format anyway. Apart from that I don't see where you are updating anything in the session after modifying the game object. Perhaps reassing the value of `$_SESSION['newGame']` before you output the JSON?

Comment: @Sherif My program actually stopped working when I removed unserialize()? I'm not sure why.

Yesss, thank you! This was the "issue"... I actually had to save it to a different session variable array, because saving it back to that one made the browser fall over :/

Sorry for the initial blunt first reply - didn't realise shift + click was needed for a new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not saving the state of the coordinates of the hits. If you are using the eloquent model, and setState is changing the attribute's value, make sure that you call `$positionObj->save()` as php does not save state on each ajax request. You will need to use a database or some sort of storage to have the server 'remember' that you clicked a specific location.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jordan!

Is $positionObj->save() meant to be an inbuilt function, or did you mean to create a function to save the session variable back?

Thanks to a slight adaption of what @sherif said, I was able to get it in the end - but I'm still curious! :)

Comment: I'm happy to hear that you got it resolved! The save method is a function defined in the Model class which your Fleet class would be extending. The Eloquent documentation can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent Happy Coding @cokan3